# I get this error Xamarin Maps

Tags: c#, xamarin

I get this error

> Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com. Reason: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'FormsViewGroup, Version=, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

help me...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When asking a question, it is helpful to provide context, for example the code that you are using. Please review the following tips on producing a [minimum example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question so that others will be able diagnose your issue more accurately.

Comment: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=23210

Answer (score 1):

I am **assuming** you do not have Google Play Services installed on your Android emulator which is required for Google Maps to be used/displayed. (more details in your question would help, code/stacktrace/...)

- Test your app on a physical device

Or

(Assuming you are using the Xamarin Android Player, but this also works on Genymotion and VisualStudio Android emulator)

- Install Google Play Services on your emulator:

> Start the Xamarin Android Player
>
> Download the proper Google Play Services .zip file from www.teamandroid.com/gapps/ .

**Note: Make sure to download the image appropriate for your version of Android.**

> Drag the .zip file onto the running emulator and drop it to install the component
>
> You will get a prompt to install the package onto the emulator which indicates the image will be restarted
>
> Once it restarts, you will get a notification that installation is completed, and the image will now have Google Maps, Google+ and support for the Google Play store.

**Note that some things do not work correctly and you may get a few errors from some of the services, but you can safely dismiss these and continue the instructions.**

> Next, you will need to associate a Google account **so that you can update the services using the Google Play store**. It should prompt you for this, but if it does not, you can go into the Google Settings and add a new account.
>
> Once you've added the account, you can then update the Google apps by opening the Google Play store application

https://university.xamarin.com/resources/how-to-install-google-play-on-android-emulator